# Provide a description for a file dialog

Tags: html

In HTML5, I can get an open file dialog with the following code:

```
<input id="fileOpenDialog" type="file" accept=".proj" />
```

(note, .abc is my own project format)

When Google Chrome opens the dialog, it shows it like this:
[image]

Is there a way to provide an additional description for the file type? I would like it to show something like "ABC Project File (.proj)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I like the suggestion, there is no attribute in the `input type=file` that supports this.

File extensions are kept on the client, and those values are shown in the dropdown.

You can find all supported attributes in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html).

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible.

That said, however, your upload form itself should clearly specify which type of file is being requested from the user; the user should know what file they are expected to load *before* selecting to chose a file.

Whilst on this subject, it's also worth noting that the [HTML5 Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29) specifies the following warning:

> **Warning:** Extensions tend to be ambiguous (e.g. there are an untold number of formats that use the ".dat" extension, and users can typically quite easily rename their files to have a ".doc" extension even if they are not Microsoft Word documents), and MIME types tend to be unreliable (e.g. many formats have no formally registered types, and many formats are in practice labeled using a number of different MIME types). Authors are reminded that, as usual, data received from a client should be treated with caution, as it may not be in an expected format even if the user is not hostile and the user agent fully obeyed the `accept` attribute's requirements.

Even if you were somehow able to rename your desired file type to "ABC Project File (.proj)", the user would still be able to upload any other file with the `.proj` extension.